# How do I write the relative acceleration between 2 points each in a rotating frame in an inertial frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Assume I have 2 rotating Frames, A & B with respect to an inertial frame I.
given points a & b each in the corresponding frame (A,B). How can I write the relative acceleration between the frames?

EDIT:

I should've added that the Frames A & B are attached to 2 different rigid bodies on which we measure points a & b respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy: you have to stablish a vector relation of their positions, and then derive.

I guess you know $\vec{Oa}$ and $\vec{Ob}$. Then

$$\vec{ab}=\vec{Ob}-\vec{Oa}$$

and now you just have to take the second time derivative of the above.

---

EDIT: in order to answer all those comments, I'm going to extend my answer.

Suppose we have an intertial frame $O$, and two rotating frames  $O'$ and $O''$.

There is a point A. $O$ sees a point $A$ given by $\vec{OA}=\vec{OO'}+\vec{O'A}$.

There is a point $B$. It holds that $\vec{OB}=\vec{OO''}+\vec{O''B}$.

The relative position between both points, seen from $O$, is

$$\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$$

Now, the relative acceleration is the second derivative of this.

$$\vec{a_{AB}}=\vec{a_B}-\vec{a_A}$$

If you want to go to any other reference frame, just un-do the vector sums.

Comment: why don't we specify the frame in which these vectors are measured?

Comment: I was using the inertial frame, that's why I wrote $O$, but vectors work in any frame, that's why we use them.

Comment: thanks, but could we write the Ob vector measured in the A frame?

Comment: The acceleration of Ob, would include the acceleration of the frame relative to the inertial frame, acceleration of the point in the rotating frame, and the rotational components (corriollis, Euler, centripetal)

Comment: After computing acceleration in the inertial frame how can I transform it back into the A frame?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments, acceleration a_{A,B} should be specified in relation to a frame, I assume in this case it's O, if we wanted that acceleration in the A frame then would I have to rotate it? R{A,O} * a^O_{AB} ?

Comment: Position vector seen from O' = position vector seen from O + $\vec{O'O}$. That's how you go back.

Comment: shouldn't there be a rotation matrix? the coordinates in A are arbitrary

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think I need them here because I'm talking about vectors as elements. How you get their coordinates is another problem. Anyway, I think you can use that with rotating vectors. Remember that time derivatives may include more terms due to the rotating coordinate system.